# CSS :after Selector

Tags: css

Hello I try to make the Css selector like

```
        .header:after{content:"Eric"; backround-color:yellow;}
```

but It not work, can your guy give me some idea please, I don't know the keyword that I can search on the internet.

Regards

Comment: "It not work" is not very descriptive.  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: So Sorry @Jim I type so quick.

Answer (score 2):

It might not work because of a typo : backround-color instead of background-color. The selector works to me : http://jsfiddle.net/MbA7J/2/

Comment: Sorry @gabitzish I'm type so quick, please forgive me.